# Action Dropdown reloads on closing navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, navigation-drawer

I am developing an app where I use a navigation drawer that selects a fragment to display the contents.
In one of the fragments, let's call it fragmentX, I use an action dropdown to select one of the methods to display data.

So far so good. Now comes the problem. Whenever I open the drawer from fragmentX and then close it, the action dropdown is reloaded, i.e. if method 2 was selected in dropdown at the time of opening the drawer, when the drawer is closed, the dropdown is reloaded and option 1 is shown.

I have followed the template provided in Eclipse to create the navigation drawer. The App structure is as follows:

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**NavigtaionDrawerFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
        return;
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**FragmentX**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {     
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.local_fragmentX, menu);
    setupDropDownSpinner();     
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private void setupDropDownSpinner() {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    ScheduleSortSpinnerAdapter mScheduleSortSpinnerAdapter = new ScheduleSortSpinnerAdapter(
            getActivity(), getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.schedule_sort_methods));        

    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mScheduleSortSpinnerAdapter, this);
}
```

The problem that I've come to close down is that the action dropdown (setupDropDownSpinner()) can only be setup from within the onCreateOptionsMenu() of fragmentX. But as drawer is closed, it invalidates the OptionMenu and therefore, OnCreateOptionMenu() of FragmentX is recalled. Is there any way to setup dropdown outside the onCreateOptionsMenu() method? I can not remove the invalidate call as it is used to switch between global option menu and local option menus of particluar fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main activity, you can listen for the drawer closing, check to see if fragmentX is the current fragment, and if so, call an interface method or just call setupDropDown directly on the fragment via the FragmentManager.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html

if you want to get even fancier, you could post an event with Otto or EventBus for drawer closed from your drawer listener.